# How to add callback for appending text to TextArea or other stuff in a class that performs parsing?

Tags: java, callback

I would like to know what is the best way in Java to add a callback (perhaps as argument since I'm using public static methods most of the time), to an external function, to do something like appending text to a text area control. I don't want to pass references to the text area though.

I'm fairly new to Java, hence the lame question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok from what I understand, you want to be able to call a method which updates text area, without directly invoking it.
i.e you simple want to send the name of the method.

In the code display the output, (you can add code here, to display it in specific text area)

But we do not want to call methods directly, we let the program invoke the methods based on call back information provided.

We use concept of Reflections to initialize classes, invoke methods etc

Class: MainCallBack.java

- we pass the name of the method to invoke,
- the function displayAnswer( int, String) will take the number to be displayed, and also the method that has to be called. (not sure if this is what you mean by CallBack)

I have added comments in each line to explain what the function does.

the following line of code within `displayAnswer` does the actual invocation.

```
methods[i].invoke(classObject, answer);
```

If you want to invoke a static method, use "null" in place of the "classObject"

```
methods[i].invoke(null, answer);
```

Created classes in package `com.callback`
In order to reduce number of lines of code, I using the Exception instead of specific exceptions.

**Class MainCallBack.java**

```
package com.callback;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class MainCallBack {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        MainCallBack mainCallBk = new MainCallBack();

        String sCallBackMethodName = "displaySumInTextArea"; //this is the name of the callback method.

        int z = 11 ;
        mainCallBk.displayAnswer( z , sCallBackMethodName );
    }
    private void displayAnswer(Integer answer , String sCallBackMethod)
    {
        try {
            Class className = Class.forName("com.callback.CallBackClass"); //will assume that we know the class name
            Constructor classConstructor = className.getConstructor(); // get the constructor of the class. 
            Object classObject = classConstructor.newInstance(); //create an instance.

            Method[] methods = className.getDeclaredMethods();   //get all methods within the class.

            for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++)
            {
                String dataMethod = methods[i].getName();   // iterate through array of methods and get each name
                if(dataMethod.equalsIgnoreCase(sCallBackMethod))  //comparing callbackname with every method in class.
                {
                    methods[i].invoke(classObject, answer);     // invoke the method if they match with what the user is calling.
                                    // if 'displaySumInTextArea( int )' was static then we would use 'null' (without quotes) in place of the classObject.
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); //use specific exceptions here
        }
    }
}
```

**class CallBackClass.java**

```
package com.callback;

public class CallBackClass {

    public void displaySumInTextArea(Integer sum)
    {
        System.out.println("Sum = " + sum); 
    }
}
```

I hope this answers your question

Comment: Is there any 'cleaner' method for doing this? Can you pass a method by reference or such? I don't know but walking the whole method list seems a bit suboptimal. I appreciate the effort put into answering, though.

Comment: @soze I don't think there is an inbuilt method in Java to do this. You will have to hack together something, or search and see if there is any third party libraries doing this. But even the third part libraries would be doing similar stuff, as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I ended up using interfaces which is a cleaner/more accurate way to do this, like in C#. However since I lack the time to elaborate an answer of my own I accepted yours.